# Problema con DISTINCT al agregar la columna ID

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta;

```
SELECT DISTINCT coordx,nis,nic,ct,medidor,coordy,comentario FROM nis_cap
```

Esta consulta me trae 544 registros;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en que si modifico la consulta para agregar el ID, `DISTINCT` no funciona como espero;

```
-- Agrege la columna id luego de coordx
SELECT DISTINCT coordx,id,nis,nic,ct,medidor,coordy,comentario FROM nis_cap
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me trae todos los registros que existen en la tabla y yo solo necesito los que las coordenadasx sean únicas.

La idea es traer los registros que tengan coordenadas únicas, imaginando que estos datos son "edificios" y en un "edificio" hay varios apartamentos, por lo que los apartamentos de un edifico heredan las coordenadas y estas estarán duplicadas en la base de datos.

Tengo una interfaz para modificar "Los edificios" pero la app se carga demasiado al tener muchos puntos en las mismas coordenadas.

Colocando la consulta sin el `primary key` todo funciona bien, hasta que lo agrego y la idea de agregar el `primary key` es modificar los datos por su `primary key`

Comment: Si quieres asegurarte que las coordenadas sean únicas puedes agregar un indice de tipo UNIQUE.

Comment: El ID generalmente es una clave primaria, cada registro poseerá un único indicador que lo identifica, hacer una consulta con DISTINCT y la clave primaria generalmente no tiene sentido por qué el mostrar el ID anula el DISTINCT.

Comment: @Juan He agregado mas datos para ponerlos en situación.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon El punto que explicas tiene lógica para mi, probablemente lo que quiero hacer no se pueda, como lo quiero hacer.

Comment: @Juan La primera coincidencia, con eso no hay problema ya que lo que se busca es modificar las propiedades del edifico no de los apartamentos.

Comment: Entoncen en la ecuación faltan los edificios. Como relacionamos x,y con los edificios, ese es el id que te falta no el de los departamentos?

Comment: @Juan Ahora que lo mencionas conviene mas normalizar la tabla, ya que no existe una tabla dedicada a esto. Gracias! ya tengo una idea mejor!